# Laravel realationship find root parent

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have `categories` table with like this structure:

```
id
title
category_id
```

**Category** model relations:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}

public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->categories()->with('subcategories');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

**Example table data:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Product Categories Group",
    "category_id": null
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Buy",
    "category_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Sale",
    "category_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Fruits",
    "category_id": 2
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Apple",
    "category_id": 4
}
```

In this case how I can check category parent is `Buy` category or `Sale` using `id`. For example how check `Apple` category parent is `Buy` or `Sale` category?

Answer (score 0):

you can use while loop until it finds parent

try this

```php
$category = Category::where('title', 'Apple')->firstOrFail();
if (!$category->category_id) {
        $parentCategory = $category;
}
while (isset($category->category_id)) {
    $category = Category::find($category->category_id);
}

return $parentCategory;
```

Comment: it has to be recursive I guess.